# move_uploaded_file moves the file into destination, but returns false, why?

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm facing a strange situation here: I have an advanced multipart file upload script, which, for example, checks for duplicate filenames by scanning the destination folder and then renames the duplicate names with iteration number. Now, the problem here is, that for some reason, script passess with green lights if no duplicates are submitted, but if duplicate is inputted, script will return false in move_upload_file part, but however, still manage to create the proper duplicate into destination folder. I was just wondering, why and how the move_upload_file function returns false, but still proceeds moving the file?

Here is simplified snippet of the script, just trying to point you out to the problem:

```
<?php
//I'll loop all the files, which are submitted (in array)
foreach($_FILES['myFiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_path) {

    //Alot of stuff (most likely unrelated) happens here

    //filepath contains both destination folder and filename
    $filepath = $destination_folder.$filename;

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $duplicate_filename = true;

        //Some more stuff happens here. Then comes the actual moving part. Before this we have found duplicates 
        //for this upload file and counted proper duplicate value. 

        $file_increment = $num_of_filename_duplicates + 1;

        while ($duplicate_filename == true) {
            if(file_exists($filepath)) {
                //Separate filename parts and make new duplicate name with increment value
                $info = pathinfo($filename);
                $basename =  basename($filename,'.'.$info['extension']);
                $newfilename = $basename."(".$file_increment.").".$info['extension'];
                $filepath = $destination_folder.$newfilename;

                //Now, this returns me false, but still creates the file into destination
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $filepath)) {
                    $file_success = true;
                    $file_increment++;
                }
                //So thats why this is true and I'll get the file_error
                else {
                    $file_error = "File error: Uploading of the file failed.";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                $duplicate_filename = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you know it's "creating the proper duplicate" in the target destination and not simply keeping the duplicate that's already there?

Comment: I don't get one thing: why you have `$file_increment++;` at the end of the last `if` statement?

Comment: @Pekka, Because I can check that from destination folder. For example. If i have test1.txt already there, and i upload another test1.txt, the script creates a new test1(1).txt and does not overwrite the duplicate.

Comment: But `move_uploaded_file()` doesn't do that, your script does. What exactly returns false?

Comment: @mastazi, yes it's useless there. It's very unlike, that $filepath will be same anymore and I would need to iterate the file_increment.

Comment: @Pekka, I've done the renaming before move_upload_file. $filepath passed to the function is now with a new destination path. if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $filepath)) returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasons can be:

> 1) If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
>   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.
>
> 2) If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

Your case seems to be 2. Try to set the following at the top of your script to see errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

**Don't try to find some magic. Just debug your code.**

Comment: I'm aware of this and I get no errors. If the second is the case, why file is still uploaded?

Comment: And if you `echo $filepath;` just before you call `move_uploaded_file`, path is right?

Comment: yes it's just right. Now I'm starting to think theres something wrong with the loop itself.

Comment: Maybe `move_uploaded_file` is executed with the same params twice and you take just the last result (which should fail)?

Comment: That sounds logic. I'll try to investigate.